# Create a COM object given a path to the exe using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, com

Using PowerShell, does anyone know how to create a COM object given a full path to the exe that implements that object? New-Object -ComObject allows a ProgID to be specified. What I want is to say something like New-Object -ComObject path_to_exe.

Our application has a COM API that I wish to exercise via PowerShell. I want to control which build (debug vs. release etc.) of our application is invoked. One workaround I can think of is to register the version of the application I want to control just before calling New-Object, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: Don't you have to register it with regsvr32 or regasm?

Answer (score 0):

COM objects are created by the SCM (service control manager), a process called activation IIRC.  Anyway, the activation process accepts either the CLSID or a ProgID.  It does not accept paths i.e. this is out of PowerShell's control.  There is one possibility having to do with [.local files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/01/24/517221.aspx) but I think that means you would need a PowerShell.exe.local file which also means the COM server would need to reside in the PowerShell dir - probably not a good idea.  Even then, you'd still have to use the ProgID.  You just wouldn't need to re-register the server.

I'd say just register the one you want to test before you instantiate it with its ProgID.